# Define a F# function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, f#, syntax-error

I have defined a F# function in my VB code as follow:

```
Dim g As Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc(Of Double, Double)
```

How can I assign g to a particular function: for example I want `g(x) = x^2`?
What is the syntax for it in VB.NET ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the goal here?

Comment: Just derive your own class from FSharpFunc, implement the Invoke() method.

Comment: My scenario here is that, I have written a function in F# to find one root of an arbitrary function within a range. F# is very impressive which I only needed to write 5 lines of code (no kidding) while in VB, I had to write around 50 lines. Thus I am trying to learn how to use both languages at the same time to ultilse their advantages. (e.g. I want to use VB for UI and F# for the math parts)

Comment: @SLaks, this is actually wrong... F# does not use typical IL functions for everything, but actually has its own internal FSharpFunc for higher-order functions, function values, etc. And difficulties arise, if you try to call some F# function from anywhere else, if the F# author was not paying special attention to be IL friendly. Because of that, F# functions can be made from any language

Comment: @N.T.C If you want to use F# and VB together in one project, I suggest, you learn how to design an IL-friendly F# assembly, such that you don't run into these kinds of problems. E.g. you might define an interface in F# that has the functions you need for your computation, and then in VB you can just implement the interface, etc. The trick is, to avoid things like DUs, function values, etc. in the VB-facing parts. This will usually make your VB code much more convenient to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what Reed says, the `FSharp.Core` library actually defines a helper method that will turn a delegate (which you can create using lambdas) into an F# function.

You can find it in `FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunction` [see MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787083.aspx). I would recommend using this function over creating a custom class, because it relies less on internal details of how the F# compiler compiles functions (you still need to know about the `FSharpFunc` type, but not as much...)

I don't know much about VB, but I suppose something like this might work:

```
Dim g = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunction(Function(x As Double) x * x)
```

Comment: it works perfectly - thank you, and this way, I don't need to create a class whenever I need to define a function.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, at least not using lambdas.

[`FSharpFunc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340302.aspx) is not a delegate - it's an abstract class, which means you'd need to subclass it and implement `Invoke`.  F# does this for you, but VB.Net (and C#) will not.

You could achieve your goal via:

```
Public Class G
    Inherits FSharpFunc(Of Double, Double)
    Public Overrides Function Invoke(value As Double) As Double
        Return value * value
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you could instantiate that class, and use it.

```
Dim g As Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc(Of Double, Double) = New G()
```